# How to retrieve values from an array of json objects in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, key-value, data-extraction

I have the following **json** :

```
[
   {
      "transition":"random_word",
      "from":"paris",
      "to":"porto",
      "date":{
         "date":"2020-05-28 11:51:25.201864",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"Europe\/Paris"
      }
   },
   {
      "transition":"rainbow",
      "from":"porto",
      "to":"faro",
      "date":{
         "date":"2020-06-06 23:10:06.878539",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"Europe\/Paris"
      }
   },
   {
      "transition":"banana",
      "from":"faro",
      "to":"rio_de_janeiro",
      "date":{
         "date":"2020-06-06 23:14:10.975099",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"Europe\/Paris"
      }
   },
   {
      "transition":"hello",
      "from":"rio_de_janeiro",
      "to":"buenos_aires",
      "date":{
         "date":"2020-06-06 23:14:15.314370",
         "timezone_type":3,
         "timezone":"Europe\/Paris"
      }
   }
]
```

Imagine I want to **retrieve the last stop** of my traveler (the value of the key "to" from the last json object. Here : buenos_aires) and **the date** (here :2020-06-06 23:14:15.314370).

How should I proceed knowing that I want to do that using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

If with "last" you mean the order in which the elements show up in the array, you can use `jsonb_array_length()` to get the length of the array and use that to obtain the last element:

```
select (the_json_column -> jsonb_array_length(the_json_column) - 1) ->> 'to' as "to",
       (the_json_column -> jsonb_array_length(the_json_column) - 1) #>> '{date,date}' as "date"
from the_table
```

The expression `jsonb_array_length(the_json_column) - 1` calculates the index of the "last" element in the array.

If your column is defined as `json` rather than `jsonb` (which it should be) you need to use the equivalent `json_array_length()` instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works :)

If I want to retrieve all destinations (here : Porto, Faro, Rio de Janeiro and Buenos Aires) with the corresponding dates, how should I proceed ?

I would like the results to be displayed in different columns (city_1 : porto, date_1 : 2020-05-28 11:51:25.201864, city_2 : faro, date_2 : 2020-06-06 23:10:06.878539, etc..)

Thank you a lot again !